# Problemas com consulta em Apache Phoenix

Tags: banco-de-dados, apache-phoenix

Olá. Eu e meu time estamos com um problema relacionado ao Apache Phoenix. Eu gostaria de saber se alguém já se deparou com esse problema antes ou se estamos fazendo algo errado.

Primeiramente, criamos a tabela a seguir:

```
create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing.PERSISTENCE
(
  FIELD_1 VARCHAR,
  FIELD_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FIELD_3 VARCHAR,
  FIELD_4 VARCHAR,
  FC1.FIELD_5 VARCHAR,
  FC1.FIELD_6 VARCHAR,
  FC2.FIELD_7 VARCHAR,
  FC3.FIELD_8 VARCHAR,
  FC3.FIELD_9 VARCHAR,
  FC3.FIELD_10 VARCHAR,
  CONSTRAINT BALANCE_EDR_PK PRIMARY KEY (FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4, FIELD_5)
) IMMUTABLE_ROWS=true SPLIT ON (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32,
            33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,
            49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64,
            65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
            81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96,
            97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112,
            113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128,
            129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
            145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160,
            161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176,
            177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192,
            193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208,
            209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224,
            225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
            241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256);
```

Após criar essa tabela, nós populamos alguns dados nela.

Quando tentamos executar a query a seguir (que aparenta estar perfeitamente correta para nós), não é retornado nenhum resultado.

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:>  SELECT * FROM testing.PERSISTENCE WHERE FIELD_2 >= 20190410 AND FIELD_2 <= 20190423 AND FIELD_1 = '5571991529969' AND FIELD_3='242' AND FIELD_5 IN  ('MyEvent') AND FIELD_4='7fde6b19-e7e3-487c-8fc5-b087029355d3';
```

Todavia, ao executar a query a seguir nós temos resultados.

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:>  SELECT * FROM testing.PERSISTENCE WHERE FIELD_2 >= 20190410 AND FIELD_2 <= 20190423 AND FIELD_1 = '5571991529969' AND FIELD_5 IN  ('MyEvent') AND FIELD_4='7fde6b19-e7e3-487c-8fc5-b087029355d3';
```

A única diferença entre elas é a ausência do FIELD_3. O estranho é que esse campo é uma PK desta tabela.

Comment: E na segunda query existe uma linha na qual FIELD_3 seja '242'? Quanto a "O estranho é que esse campo é uma PK desta tabela." me parece que o campo faz parte de primary key e não que ele seja primary key.

Comment: Isso, ele é parte da PK

Comment: Então não entendi seu estranhamento quanto a possível não existência de uma linha em que este valor de campo não ocorra.

Comment: Se fosse o caso dele trazer com o campo presente e não trazer na ausência dele, faria sentido. O problema é que acontece justamente o contrário. Quando tenho o FIELD_3 na query e todas demais condições ele não retorna o esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Para referência de outros, nossa solução temporária foi a de fazer N consultas e depois fazer o merge dos resultados.

Com certeza existe uma solução melhor. Caso alguém saiba qual seja, por favor, responda esse tópico.